# Promise is returned from a model hook, Ember.js does not block until the promise is resolved

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

here is the issue i am trying to resolve.
I am trying to retrieve contact record from store via query string params (fields: id and tab). i can see the contact model being retrieved in the browser console .

since find operation is being executed on query params the response is array of one contact record.
that's why in the controller code beneath i am extracting the contact model using contact.get('firstObject').

however nothing gets rendered in the browser as  before this whole operation is done the template gets rendered.

I dont understand this behavior.  **since i am wrapping this operation in RSVP promise call.
till this  promise is returned from this model hook, Ember.js should block until the promise is resolved .** please let me know what is going wrong here.

```
export default  Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   model:function(){
   var self = this;
   return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          self.store.find('contact',{id:1, tab: "contactInfo"}).then(function(contact) {
              contact.get('firstObject');
          });

          });
    }.property('model')       
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. Apart from some redundant code, you should of course return your firstObject. This should work:

```
 model:function(){
   return this.store.find('contact',{id:1, tab: "contactInfo"}).then(function(contact) {
              return contact.get('firstObject');
    });
```

Promises are ember's approach on handling asynchronous logic and the whole goal is not to block the whole application. When the data gets in, the template will be updated.

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt work as well.. somehow before the contact object is returned in the callback the template gets rendered. hence i am not able to display the model..

Comment: Ah now I see it, you are doing this in the controller, that's what's wrong. If you do this from within a route it will work. Setup your controller like this: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/